# How to use double star glob in Go?

Tags: go, glob

It seems like `Go` is one of few languages that does not seem to understand the double star ("globstar") syntax for file globbing. At least this does not seems to work as expected:

```
filepath.Glob(dir + "/**/*.bundle/*.txt")
```

Am I missing something about the `filepath` implementation?
Is there a library around that does support this?

Comment: Where did you see that `filepath.Glob` should support `**`?

Comment: The docs are quite unspecific. "The pattern may describe hierarchical names such as /usr/*/bin/ed" and most globbing implementations I know support it.

Comment: while not uncommon, `**` isn't really a standard thing. The docs are pretty specific: `'*' matches any sequence of non-Separator characters`. http://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Match

Comment: The docs at http://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Glob are not. Looking under the hood I now see that `Match` is being used - but that should be irrelevant for the documentation. At least there should be a reference.

Comment: I don't think it's up to the docs to specify everything that it *doesn't* do. There's no mention of other shell globbing patterns (more common, and around longer than `**`), but I wouldn't assume it does those either.

Comment: I don't think it should specify what it doesn't do either. The problem is the imprecision of "The pattern may describe hierarchical names such as" and the lack of a reference to Match. I don't think it's too much to ask for a link to where the spec is.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The `filepath.Glob` implementation uses `filepath.Match` under the hood. Turns out [the specs for that](http://golang.org/pkg/path/filepath/#Match) do not cover the quite common (`.gitignore`, `zsh`) double star pattern. By no means the same - but for my use case I managed to work around it with this little function:

```
func glob(dir string, ext string) ([]string, error) {

  files := []string{}
  err := filepath.Walk(dir, func(path string, f os.FileInfo, err error) error {
    if filepath.Ext(path) == ext {
      files = append(files, path)
    }
    return nil
  })

  return files, err
}
```

I am still open for a better implementation with proper double star matching.

Comment: I know that `[]string` is a splice of strings, but what is `[]string{}`?  Why add {} at the end? Thanks for this

Comment: @Leahcim: `[]string{}` is a slice literal, functionally equivalent to `make([]string, 0)`.

Comment: I made this, which does what I need - it lets you do `matches, err := filepathx.Globs(strings.Split(glob, "**")).Expand()` https://github.com/yargevad/filepathx

Answer (score 5):

I've written a small [extension library](https://github.com/yargevad/filepathx) that supports double star globbling. With this directory structure:

```
$ find a
a
a/b
a/b/c.d
a/b/c.d/e.f
```

You can use `a/**/*.*` to match everything under the `a` directory that contains a dot, like so:

```golang
package main

import (
  "fmt"

  "github.com/yargevad/filepathx"
)

func main() {
  matches, err := filepathx.Glob("./a/**/*.*")
  if err != nil {
    panic(err)
  }

  for _, match := range matches {
    fmt.Printf("MATCH: [%v]\n", match)
  }
}
```

Which outputs:

```
$ go run example.go
MATCH: [a/b/c.d]
MATCH: [a/b/c.d/e.f]
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is something similar. You can pass a callback to filter the files:

```
package main

import (
   "io/fs"
   "path/filepath"
)

func glob(root string, fn func(string)bool) []string {
   var files []string
   filepath.WalkDir(root, func(s string, d fs.DirEntry, e error) error {
      if fn(s) {
         files = append(files, s)
      }
      return nil
   })
   return files
}

func main() {
   files := glob(".", func(s string) bool {
      return filepath.Ext(s) == ".txt"
   })
   for _, file := range files {
      println(file)
   }
}
```