# Html Template files not being searched

Tags: go, goland

**About**

I am trying to find a file which is present under many nested sub folders in GO Programming language.

**Issue Details**

There are two code blocks below. First one **(Working Code)** is working fine because of this below line of code

```
templates = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("templates/front/auth/login/*.html"))
```

Second code block **(Not Working Code)** is not working due to below line.

```
templates = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("*.*"))
```

When I try to print the html searched files using below code...it lists only main.go

```
fmt.Println(templates.DefinedTemplates())
```

[image]

Above is directory Structure. Go folder is root. It contains two child folders.

> 1. static folder - for keeping css and js folders
> 2. templates - for keeping html files

**Working Code**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
)

var templates *template.Template

func loginhandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { 
    templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "login.html", nil)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    switch r.URL.Path {
    case "/login":
        loginhandler(w, r)
    }
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    
    templates = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("templates/front/auth/login/*.html"))
    fmt.Println(templates.DefinedTemplates())

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

**Not Working Code**

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
)

var templates *template.Template

func loginhandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { 
    templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "login.html", nil)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    switch r.URL.Path {
    case "/login":
        loginhandler(w, r)
    }
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    
    templates = template.Must(template.ParseGlob("*.*"))
    fmt.Println(templates.DefinedTemplates())

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

**Please let me know if you need more info**

Answer (score 2):

The argument `"*.*"` matches only files in the current directory with any extension. It does not traverse the subdirectories.

In [Go's `filepath.Glob` pattern](https://pkg.go.dev/path/filepath#Match), `*` matches any sequence of non-Separator characters, and [`**` is not supported](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26809999/6309) like in some shells (bash v4) or other languages like Python. So it cannot match files in subdirectories.

If you want to parse all `.html` files under `templates` directory including its subdirectories, you need to give the path explicitly.

Since you mentioned that the directory structure might contain multiple nested subfolders, and your files are in `.html` format, unfortunately, you will need to list out each directory manually. Go's standard library does not support recursive search with `**`.

However, you can write a function to walk through the directories and select the needed files.
Here is [an example](https://go.dev/play/p/9E0Y5nHazV5):

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "html/template"
    "net/http"
    "path/filepath"
    "strings"
)

var templates *template.Template

func loginhandler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) { 
    templates.ExecuteTemplate(w, "login.html", nil)
}

func handler(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
    switch r.URL.Path {
    case "/login":
        loginhandler(w, r)
    }
}

func parseHTMLTemplates(root string) (*template.Template, error) {
    var allFiles []string

    err := filepath.Walk(root, func(path string, info os.FileInfo, err error) error {
        if err != nil {
            return err
        }
        if !info.IsDir() && strings.HasSuffix(info.Name(), ".html") {
            allFiles = append(allFiles, path)
        }
        return nil
    })
    if err != nil {
        return nil, err
    }

    templates, err := template.ParseFiles(allFiles...)
    return templates, err
}

func main() {
    http.HandleFunc("/", handler)
    
    var err error
    templates, err = parseHTMLTemplates("./templates")
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
    
    fmt.Println(templates.DefinedTemplates())

    http.ListenAndServe(":8080", nil)
}
```

That `parseHTMLTemplates` function will recursively walk through the `templates` directory and collect all `.html` files. Then it will parse all those files and return the `*template.Template`. That way, you do not have to manually list out each directory.

Note: In the code, the `filepath.Walk` function is used to traverse all files in the directory tree rooted at `root`. The function provided to `filepath.Walk` is invoked for each file or directory in the tree, including `root`. If `filepath.Walk` encounters an error, it will be passed to the function provided to `filepath.Walk`. If the function returns an error, the walk is stopped.

The `strings.HasSuffix(info.Name(), ".html")` check ensures that we only consider `.html` files for our template. If you have other file types to consider, you may want to update this check or make it more sophisticated.